# recursive function JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have coded the below recursive function. I want the user as soon as he is clicking the button, the picture is changing and repeating itself. However, once it reached the end of the loop, it stopped execution.
Can you please help me to override this fault?

Note: you can try it with your src pictures
Html:

```
<button  onclick="show();">show pictures</button>
<ul id="UL">
    <li id=""><img src="imagegs.jpg" class= "img1"  ></li>
    <li id=""><img src="images.jpg" class= "img1"  ></li>
    <li id=""><img src="imags.jpg" class= "img1"  > </li>
    <li id=""><img src="imas.jpg" class= "img1"  ></li>
    <li id=""><img src="coffee.jpg" class= "img1" ></li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
ul{
    list-style: none;
  }
ul li img{
    position: absolute;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
}
ul li{
    display: none;
}
```

js:

```
var count=0; 

function show(){
    var pictures = document.images.length;
    var showPicture = document.getElementById('UL');
    var i = count % pictures; // to maintain the picture index not exeeding its length
    showPicture.children[i].style.display = "inline";
    count++;
    console.log("count "+count+" index: "+i); 
}
```

Comment: well you show the image, but it appears you never hide the others....

Comment: You have neither a loop nor recursion.

Comment: @SLaks I suppose the "loop" is ment on every click

Comment: All the function does is un-hide an image on each click. Once they're all displayed, that's it. There's nothing more to do.

Comment: So, how can I hide it again after it displayed?

Comment: select the previous one and hide it...

Answer (score 0):

Remove `display` inline style from previous image before showing another:

```
    showPicture.children[i].style.display = "";
```

```css
ul{
    list-style: none;
  }
ul li img{
    position: absolute;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
}
ul li{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script>
var count=document.images.length - 1; 
var i = 1;

function show(){
    var pictures = document.images.length;
    var showPicture = document.getElementById('UL');
 
    
    showPicture.children[i].style.display = "";    
    count++;
    
    i = count % pictures; // to maintain the picture index not exeeding its length
    showPicture.children[i].style.display = "inline";
    console.log("count "+count+" index: "+i); 
}
</script>

<button  onclick="show();">show pictures</button>
<ul id="UL">
    <li id=""><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x90.png?text=1" class= "img1"  ></li>
    <li id=""><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x90.png?text=2" class= "img1"  ></li>
    <li id=""><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x90.png?text=3" class= "img1"  > </li>
    <li id=""><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x90.png?text=4" class= "img1"  ></li>
    <li id=""><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x90.png?text=5" class= "img1" ></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not hide the image after you show it. It is easier just to toggle a class and remember the last one that was selected. Other option is to just read the last index.

```js
var count = 0;
var last;
var showPicture = document.getElementById('UL');
var lis = showPicture.querySelectorAll("li")

function show() {
  var i = count % lis.length; 
  if (last) last.classList.remove("active");
  last = lis[i]
  last.classList.add("active");
  count++;
}
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

ul li img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
}

ul li {
  display: none;
}

ul li.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="show();">show pictures</button>
<ul id="UL">
  <li><img src="http://placekitten.com/100/300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placekitten.com/300/300"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placekitten.com/400/300"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is really what I'm looking for.

Thank you.